# Format receipt and print using a Bluetooth printer in React Native

Tags: react-native, printing, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently, I can print to a BLE printer. But I want to format my receipt, especially for adding `border`s and a `background-color` to titles as seen below:

I want to add texts with backgrounds as shown in the screenshot and print them to a BLE printer using ReactNative.

> [image]

I have tried to add HTML tags formatted with CSS `border`s and `background-color: black;` but the printer will produce HTML code in the receipt like normal text.